# XML - targeting node attribute, push into a Flash AS3 array

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to push just the contents of the "txt" attribute in each "question" tag into an array named "questions" in AS3 Flash. Here is an excerpt from my xml file.

```
<question id='Q1' uId='99036'  no_ans='2' txt='In a flat structure employees are not expected to provide their bosses with their opinions.' feedback='' type='MC' passingWeight='1' url='media/'>
    <answer id='Q1A1' uId='311288' txt='True' weight='0'/>
    <answer id='Q1A2' uId='311289' txt='False' weight='1'/>
</question>
<question id='Q2' uId='99037'  no_ans='2' txt='In a hierarchy, information typically flows downward.' feedback='' type='MC' passingWeight='1' url='media/'>
    <answer id='Q2A1' uId='311290' txt='True' weight='1'/>
    <answer id='Q2A2' uId='311291' txt='False' weight='0'/>
</question>
<question id='Q3' uId='99038'  no_ans='2' txt='Someone who keeps many projects going at one time is an example of someone who is flexible-time oriented.' feedback='' type='MC' passingWeight='1' url='media/'>
    <answer id='Q3A1' uId='311292' txt='True' weight='1'/>
    <answer id='Q3A2' uId='311293' txt='False' weight='0'/>
</question>
```

Here is my attempt at a loop:

```
// get number of questions
    trace(myXML.question.length());
    numberOfQuestions = myXML.question.length();

    //loop and push questions into questions array at top
    for (var i:int = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
        trace("Hello.");
        questions.push(myXML.question.@txt);
        trace(questions);
    }
```

This just pushes all 9 of the questions at once into each position of the array. I wanted 1 question per array position. I'm not sure how to use the id attribute in the question tag to differentiate each question.

**EDIT:** I tried this and I can access the questions texts using **getQuestionAt(2)** from within the **processXML** function, but not outside of it.

```
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("html/VUBZ7318CROSSCULTUREQUIZ/manifest.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

    //trace(myXML.question)

    // get number of questions
    trace(myXML.question.length());
    numberOfQuestions = myXML.question.length();

    //Question list
    var questions:Object = {};
    //Extracting question from xml
    for each (var item:XML in myXML.question) {
        questions[item. @ id] = item. @ txt;
    }
    //Some method for fetching question from question list
    function getQuestionAt( index:Number ):String {
        if (questions["Q" + index] == undefined) {
            throw new Error("Wrong index for question!!!");
        }
        return questions["Q"+index];
    }

    //Getting question from list
    trace( "Here is question No 2:\t" + getQuestionAt(2) );


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new layer, which have only one frame, and make that frame's length as long as your total frames are(for instance 6 as long). Then put this code in that frame.

```
//Question list
var questions:Object; 
//Some method for fetching question from question list
function getQuestionAt( index:Number ):String{
    if( questions["Q"+index] == undefined ){
        throw new Error("Wrong index for question!!!");
    }
    return questions["Q"+index];
}
```

Then add these lines into your `processXML` function

```
function processXML():*{
 //.....Your 'myXML' is here....
 questions = {};
 //Extracting question from xml
 for each(var item:XML in myXML.question){
    questions[item.@id] = item.@txt;
 }
}
```

Call `getQuestionAt` whenever you want to get questions. You can call that function in any frame, because it's 'visible' on all frames.

Comment: How do I access one of the questions from a different frame in the fla?
I tried to populate a textfield with **text_txt.htmlText = getQuestionAt(2);** on frame 6, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Create new layer, which have only one frame, and make that frame's length as long as your total frames are(for instance 6 as long). Then add AS code in that frame. In that case, you can call the function in any frame, because it's 'visible' on all frames.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it still does not work... is it because I put your code inside the **processXML()** function? See my edit above. It works inside the function, but not outside, or from anywhere else in the fla.

Comment: This works now.
I have all of the game quiz actionscript on a frame, and then in a separate frame that extends across all frames I put the getQuestionAt() function. I can populate all the questions using this:
**question1_mc.question1_txt.htmlText = getQuestionAt(2);**

Comment: I tried to do the same thing for the answers text, but get an error... see **"EDIT 2"** in my initial post above.

Comment: @livi1717 It is a different question. So create a new question,but not update the first one!

Comment: Ok, here is the new question...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772832/the-continuing-saga-of-xml-targeting-node-attribute-push-into-a-flash-as3-ar

Answer (score 0):

You XML is set up just a tad wrong. In AS3 you need a root node. A root node is not accessible it's just kind of a wrapper. In your case Question is your root node which is not accessible, which will make those attributes not accessible also. So put a wrapper around your xml. I could be wrong about not being able to access the root node attributes however I am correct on your XML not being proper. And adding the wrapper just makes like easier.

```
<questions>
  <question id='Q1' uId='99036'  no_ans='2' txt='In a flat structure employees are not expected to provide their bosses with their opinions.' feedback='' type='MC' passingWeight='1' url='media/'>
      <answer id='Q1A1' uId='311288' txt='True' weight='0'/>
      <answer id='Q1A2' uId='311289' txt='False' weight='1'/>
  </question>
  <question id='Q2' uId='99037'  no_ans='2' txt='In a hierarchy, information typically flows downward.' feedback='' type='MC' passingWeight='1' url='media/'>
      <answer id='Q2A1' uId='311290' txt='True' weight='1'/>
      <answer id='Q2A2' uId='311291' txt='False' weight='0'/>
  </question>
  <question id='Q3' uId='99038'  no_ans='2' txt='Someone who keeps many projects going at one time is an example of someone who is flexible-time oriented.' feedback='' type='MC' passingWeight='1' url='media/'>
      <answer id='Q3A1' uId='311292' txt='True' weight='1'/>
      <answer id='Q3A2' uId='311293' txt='False' weight='0'/>
  </question>
</questions>
```

And then grab the attribute like so.

```
var questions:XMLList =  new XMLList( e.target.data.question )
for each ( var question:XML in questions){
  trace( question.@txt )
}
```

Comment: Also please never ever "NEST" functions it is just bad.

Comment: Thats just an excerpt of the xml, it does have a root node and is formatted properly. The xml file was too long and contained too much irrelevant data to post it all.

Comment: I tried this, but it gives the following error.
TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert Object@29328c41 to XMLList.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not XML, but an XMLList, and it is perfectly acceptable.

You don't need to loop through. You can get another XMLList like this. An XMLList is like an array of XML, but in this case you won't have fully formed nodes, but just the contents of all the attributes.

It will go something like this:

```
var questionTxt:XMLList = yourQuestions.@txt;//yourQuestions contains your originalXMLList as shown above
```

Now, you can access each text element as:

```
var stem:String = String(questionTxt[0]);
```

If for some reason you absolutely *must* have an Array, you can do this:

```
var questions:Array = new Array();
for (var i:int = 0; i< questionTxt.length(); i++) {
    questions[i] = questionTxt[i];
}
```

However, it looks like a lot of work for nothing, since you can simply use the XMLList as it is by accessing it with e4x. What is your full goal?

I just looked at your question a bit more carefully, and all you really need to do is this:

```
protected var questions:XMLList;
public function processXML(e:Event):void {
            myXML = XML(e.target.data);
            questions = myXML.question;

            // get number of questions
            trace(myXML.question.length());
}

public function getQuestionAt( index:Number ):String {
            if (questions[index] == undefined) {
                throw new Error("Wrong index for question!!!");
            }
            return questions[index].attribute('txt');
}       

public function get numberOfQuestions():int {
    return myXML.question.length();
}
```

Comment: I client has a purchased quiz game in flash 
http://elearningbrothers.com/product_demos/004_flashgames/002_gameshowdemo/demo.htm
that I am trying to make dynamic... it is currently not dynamic. I don't want to recreate the whole thing. A CMS currently generates the quiz questions in the xml file. I just need to load the questions and answers in the first frame, and be able to access them in other frames throughout the fla file. I cannot use external .as files, so all the code most be internal.

Comment: What is preventing you from using as files? But even so, you can alter what I gave you to work with frame scripts (even if it makes you feel a little ill to do so...I completely get it, since I'm working AS2 every day now).