# The continuing saga of "XML - targeting node attribute, push into a Flash AS3 array"

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash

I have another question that stems from this previously asked question:
[XML - targeting node attribute, push into a Flash AS3 array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727946/xml-targeting-node-attribute-push-into-a-flash-as3-array). I was told to ask a new question rather than update the old one.

Here is an excerpt of my XML file. (It is properly formatted, and has a root node, etc., but is too long to post the entire thing. Below is just the part I am concerned with.

```
<question id='Q1' uId='99036'  no_ans='2' txt='In a flat structure employees are not expected to provide their bosses with their opinions.' feedback='' type='MC' passingWeight='1' url='media/'>
    <answer id='Q1A1' uId='311288' txt='True' weight='0'/>
    <answer id='Q1A2' uId='311289' txt='False' weight='1'/>
</question>
<question id='Q2' uId='99037'  no_ans='2' txt='In a hierarchy, information typically flows downward.' feedback='' type='MC' passingWeight='1' url='media/'>
    <answer id='Q2A1' uId='311290' txt='True' weight='1'/>
    <answer id='Q2A2' uId='311291' txt='False' weight='0'/>
</question>
<question id='Q3' uId='99038'  no_ans='2' txt='Someone who keeps many projects going at one time is an example of someone who is flexible-time oriented.' feedback='' type='MC' passingWeight='1' url='media/'>
    <answer id='Q3A1' uId='311292' txt='True' weight='1'/>
    <answer id='Q3A2' uId='311293' txt='False' weight='0'/>
</question>
```

This is what i am using to obtain the **txt** attribute from the **question** tag.

```
//load the xml
var myXML:XML;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("html/BlahBlah/manifest.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);
    trace(myXML.*);



    //.....Your 'myXML' is here....
    questions = {};
    //Extracting question from xml
    for each (var item:XML in myXML.question) {
        questions[item. @ id] = item. @ txt;
    }

}
```

Below is a function is on a separate frame that extends the length of the fla.

```
//Question list
var questions:Object;
//Some method for fetching question from question list
function getQuestionAt( index:Number ):String {
    if (questions["Q" + index] == undefined) {
        throw new Error("Wrong index for question!!!");
    }
    return questions["Q"+index];
}
```

Referencing that function, I then use this to target a specific txt attribute to populate a dynamic textfield:

```
question1_mc.question_txt.htmlText = "<b>Question 1: </b><br>"+ getQuestionAt(1);
```

What I now need is a way to grab the txt attribute value from the answer tags and be able to access them from anywhere in the fla. Keep in mind that there are two answers for every question. ie:

< answer id='Q1A1' uId='311288' txt='**True**' weight='0'/ >
< answer id='Q1A2' uId='311289' txt='**False**' weight='1'/ >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's an easier way to do this. Rather than loading the XML and storing your questions in an Object, just reference the XML Object. The XML is already an Object, so there's no reason to parse it into another Object. Plus, you'll be able to pull all the information you need as you need it. Here's how I would suggest doing this:

```js
var myXML:XML;

var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
myLoader.load(new URLRequest("html/BlahBlah/manifest.xml"));

function complete(e:Event):void {
    myLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, complete);
    myXML = new XML(e.target.data);

    //Data for question 1
    trace(getQuestionByIndex(1).@txt); // Question
    for each (var o:Object in getAnswersByQuestionIndex(1)) {
        trace(o.@txt); // Answers
    }
}

function getQuestionByIndex(index:int):XMLList {
    return myXML.question.(@id=="Q"+index);
}

function getAnswersByQuestionIndex(index:int):XMLList {
    return getQuestionByIndex(index).answer;
}
```

Comment: The trace output works fine on the first frame. How would I populate 3 textfields on say frame 6 like below?

**question1_txt.htmlText = ?
answer1_txt.htmlText = ?
answer2_txt.htmlText = ?**

Comment: if you define your functions on the first frame and load your xml before you progress, then you should be able to call the same functions. question1_txt.htmlText = getQuestionByIndex(1).@txt and answer1_txt.htmlText = getAnswersByQuestionIndex(1)[0].@txt