# AS3/Flash: XML as datagrid data provider

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, datagrid, dataprovider

listI have something like this:

```
<list>
    <Name Date="18/12/2013">ALPHA</Name>
    <Name Date="05/05/2014">ALLAN LTD</Name>
    <Name Date="01/05/2014">ALLAN &amp; PINKER</Name>
    ...        
</list>
```

I need to populate a datagrid formated like:

```
Name | Date
```

I have no problems setting the name column values, but I can't get the date column filled.

The function I'm using says:

```
var list:Array = new Array();
listXML..Name.(list.push({Name:text()}));
fullList.dataGrid.dataProvider = new DataProvider(list);
```

How may I populate the Date column?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can access date attribute by using

```
listXml.list.name[i].@Date
```

for more info check [XML - targeting node attribute, push into a Flash AS3 array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9727946/xml-targeting-node-attribute-push-into-a-flash-as3-array)

Comment: Thanks ToniK. I don't have problems getting the attributes and values but populating the datagrid.